# Remove Layers when selecting next layer from drop-down list

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I had created drop-down List and get the all layer from Dynamic Map Services now 
Am just trying to show selected layer on the Map which is selected by drop-down list and remove all previous layer  when selecting next.

```
 var removlayr =  [bloc, majortown, landlocatn, hotsprig, erthquak, distHq, raiway, national, majorroads, geologi, drain, activ, wind, water, tecton, landl, earthzone, ste, distr];
            var i;

            for(i = 0; i < removlayr.length; i++)
               {
                    map.removeLayer(removlayr[i]);
                }
            removlayr.length = 0;
            alert("layer Removed");
```

Comment: What is the question ? what is your code not working ?

Comment: My question is that, How can remove map layer ..? i want display only current layer which is selected by dropdown list and remove previous layer from the map .